# Download file from NodeJS Server to local machine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, download, path

I want to download a textFile from the NodeJS server to the clients local machine with AngularJS as frontend. Where the client storage path is on it's local machine in downloads/testdownload.

in my backend I have:

```
router.get('/upload', function(req, res){
    var data= fs.readFileSync('../uploads/'+ file);
      fs.writeFile(??+req.file.filename, file, function(err){
          if(err){
              return console.log(err);
          }
          console.log('Saved File: ' + req.file.filename);
      })
})
```

in my Angular:

```
this.download= function(){
        $http.get('/creations/upload').then(function success(response){
                    console.log(response.data);

            }, function error(response){
              response.data;
         })
    }
```

I linked this function with a button. 
What path do I have to write in the nodejs fs.writeFile function to save the file to the local machine /downloads/testfile?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.. here i used busboy for posting and getting file.

This is back-end code. Just you have to call this api from front-end.

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs-extra');


//Get file
router.get('/:file', function(req, res, next) {
  //this is where your file will be downloaded    
  var filenamewithpath = '/home/downloads/' + req.params.file;

  if (!fs.existsSync(filename)){
    res.status(404).json({'message' : 'file not found'})
    return;
  }
  res.download(filename , fileToShow)
});

//Post file
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {    
  req.pipe(req.busboy);
  req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {    
    var fstream = fs.createWriteStream('/home/temp/' + filename);   
    file.pipe(fstream);    
    fstream.on('close', function () {
      res.status(201).json({file: filename});
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the full path of the file in server, you can put that in an html anchor tag to download it right?

```
<a href="http://<path to file>">Download</a>
```